# Draw an image as an HTML table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/0r16e802/4/

What I am trying to do is taking the image and draw it as an HTML table 
2 big problem in my algorithm

1. I can seem to be able to draw the images and only the first image is loaded in the first row
2. big problem in the size and the `background-position`

   ```
    var Append="";
   $(document).ready(function(){
     var row=2;
     var ItemPerRow=10;
     CreateEmojiTable(row, ItemPerRow);

   function CreateEmojiTable(row, ItemsPerRow){
     Append+="<table width='99%' style='padding-top:3px;'>";
    for(var i=0;i<row;i++)
    {
       Append+="<tr>";
       DrawEmoji(ItemsPerRow, i);
      Append+="</tr>";
    }
    Append+="</table>";    
   $("#emoji_container").html(Append);
     }
       function DrawEmoji(ItemsPerRow, r){
      var size=16;
       for(var i=0;i<ItemsPerRow;i++){
      Append+="<td>"
      Append+="<div class='emoji' style='background-position:0px -"+parseInt(r*i*size)+"px;'></div>";
     Append+="</td>";
     }
    }
    });
   ```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ah14oaup/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT: corrected indexing**

As suggested by Jovan, the indexing should be as he says:

```
(r*ItemsPerRow + i) * size
```

But it's still misaligned so you'll have to correct it like this:

```
(r*ItemsPerRow + i) * size - 2
```

Then, you don't want to go beyond the actual maximum index, which is 262, or you'll have repetitions and misalignments as I told in the comment above.

Here is the full solution. It fixes indexing, alignment and maximum index: http://jsfiddle.net/0r16e802/12/

---

The emojis in the image are aligned to 17 pixels, not 16.

```
var size=17;
```

This aligns them to one another, but you'll still have to solve the border conditions, which are 1 pixel off.

To do this, fix the CSS by 1 pixel:

```
height:16px;
```

Finally, fix the size computation by subtracting 1:

```
parseInt(r*i*size - 1)
```

Here is the solution: http://jsfiddle.net/0r16e802/5/

Comment: how did you know the exact size of the image ?

Comment: I don't. I just looked closely on how the offset between one and the following emoji shifts and realized it is in fixed increments. That's a common case when doing stuff like this so maybe by experience I put 17 instead of 16 pixels and... BAM! :D

Comment: Still needs changes http://jsfiddle.net/ah14oaup/1/ changed two lines. `DrawEmoji(ItemsPerRow,i*ItemsPerRow);` and `Append+="<div class='emoji' style='background-position:0px -"+parseInt(r*i*size - 1)+"px;'></div>";`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think any of the previously posted answers are correct, even if they do happen to work for the first two rows.

The way your sprite is organized, you are looking for:
**parseInt( (r*ItemsPerRow + i) * size)**

Comment: Could you perhaps show a fiddle demonstrating the difference?

Comment: Sorry, got pulled off to a meeting.  But I see that pid now updated his answer to perfection.

Answer (score -1):

As @pid already said, the sizing was somewhat out by a pixel but also the first row repeats because of `i=0` The offset height of the first row ends up being worked out as 0.  You also have a 'squidgy' factor for whatever reason of needing to -2 from the height to make them align properly, probably an issue with the original image.

```
function DrawEmoji(ItemsPerRow, r) {
        var size = 17;
        for (var i = 0; i < ItemsPerRow; i++) {
            Append += "<td>"
            Append += "<div class='emoji' style='background-position:0px -" + parseInt((r + 1) * (i + 1) * size - 2) + "px;'></div>";
            Append += "</td>";
        }
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0r16e802/9/

Comment: That was on my TODO list for the day *Task 347:- Save a life* :)

Comment: Definitely the better solution. I didn't realize there was an error in indexing and that there were many more emojis :) But when I put in 60 rows or so, at a certain point they misalign again. The source image must have an alignment error.

Comment: i'll just draw them nice borders and fix the padding and i guess everything will be fine thank you :)

Comment: @pid Yes I also saw that alignment error.  The image is 4469 px which doesn't divide cleanly by either 15,16 or 17! So i guess there is a bit of overrage/underrage somewhere.

Comment: @epascarello Not sure what you mean? No zero?

Comment: You are missing the first icon. It is actually worse than that, the icons repeat in a pattern.

Comment: @epascarello Doh! - I see what you mean!

Comment: @Sora please can you unaccept this answer and accept pid, then notify me and I'll delete this one as it's not quite correct for reasons outlined by them.